# Пытаюсь создать список со спец.символами на Python

Tags: python, list

Создаю список из строки на Python, но что-то пошло не так.
Еще Пайчарм ругается на строку в функции: "PEP 8: W605 invalid escape sequence '*'"
Вот код:

```
special_symbols = list('@№$%^&\*()')
print(special_symbols)
```

Такой вывод:

```
['@', '№', '$', '%', '^', '&', '\\', '*', '(', ')']
```

Почему удваивается символ?

Comment: это нормально, он в любом случае хранится как ```\```

Comment: А почему тогда в принте он сдвоенный?

Comment: @codeflower потому что это управляющий символ, и чтобы внутри строки в консоли он выводился как обычный символ он экранируется удвоением

Answer (score 1):

Обратный слеш `\` является escape символом. его приходится экранировать еще одним `\` чтобы явно задать что это буквально символ `\`.
Аналогично можно экранировать например кавычки.
Чтобы Pycharm не ругался можно написать так

```
special_symbols = list(r'@№$%^&\*()')
print(special_symbols)
```

Этим самым мы указываем, что это raw string. Т.е. все символы надо интепретировать буквально.